# how to implement css horizontal menu with variable width submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu I would like to implement. It can sometimes drill down 3 or 4 layers so I'm trying to optimize space taken up by each menu. I'd like to have each ul set to width: auto, the only problem is I can't set the right/left property reliably for where the next submenu should appear. Here's some code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="top-level-menu horizontal-multimenu">
    <li><a href="#">L360 Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Liquidity Risk Monitor</a>
      <ul class="second-level-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Indicators</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stress Levels</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Sources and Assumptions</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Source of Funds</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Funding Assumptions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Data</a>
      <ul class="second-level-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Transfer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Table</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Reports</a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Risk Monitor</a>
        <ul class="subsecond-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Scorecard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DCG ALCO Data</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Historical</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Prior Values</a>
            <ul class="subsecond-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Conditional Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Conditional Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Conditional Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Conditional Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Conditional Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Conditional Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Stress Reports</a>
        <ul class="subsecond-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Footnotes</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Liquidity Availability Analysis</a>
            <ul class="subsecond-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Base Case</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Exexcutive Summary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Liquidity Forecast</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Worksheets</a>
        <ul class="subsecond-level-menu">

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Package Creator</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Memoranda</a>
        <ul class="subsecond-level-menu">

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Menu Styles */

.subsecond-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 999px;
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.subsecond-level-menu>li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.subsecond-level-menu>li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu>li
{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.second-level-menu>li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu>li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: /*150px*/auto;
    background: #999999;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
.top-level-menu>li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu li:hover>ul
{
     /*On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: block;
  right: -300px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*padding: 0 0 0 10px;*/
  margin: 0 auto;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: inline;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
.top-level-menu li{whitespace: no-wrap;}
```

This should work, but all the .subsecond-level-menu's are required to be x px wide so I know where to put them.

Do you think it would be better to assign id's to each submenu and then just assign static widths/right's to each or try to make it happen with some javascript?

I've been wrestling with the js attempt for a while, but it doesn't quite seem to the submenu widths. Here's that code that I've been working on if you're curious:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.top-level-menu').find('li').hover(
    function(e){
      $(e.target).css('background-color', 'red');
      var item =  $(this);
      console.log('The child list is considered hidden: ' + $(e.target).children('ul').is(':hidden') + ', Child width: '+$(e.target).children('ul').outerWidth() + 'px');
      $(e.target).children('ul').css({
        'right': (-1 * $(e.target).children('ul').outerWidth()) + 'px',
        'opacity': '1',
        'display': 'block'
      });
    },
    function(e){
      $(e.target).css('background-color', '');
      var item =  $(this),
          emptyCss = {
            'right' : '',
            'opacity' : '',
            'display': ''};
      item.children('ul').css(emptyCss);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a percentage width, say `width:80%` on the child `ul`'s combined with a left/right float to bump them around?

Comment: But if the child ul's have content that needs to be wider than it's parent li (sometimes much wider), won't that cause some issues off the bat?

Comment: i suppose that would, maybe if the parent `ul`'s parent had `overflow:visible`, the child content would show correctly regardless of the parent's width? Would you be able to build a demo as a fiddle?

Comment: you can fork this codepen: http://codepen.io/jgonyer1/pen/Dvlmx